# Number of poker hands (5 card hands)

Tags: combinatorics

Please point out if there are flaws in my reasoning. Thanks!

So I want to count how many 5 card poker hands are there such that we have two distinct pairs (i.e. 2 aces, 2 10's) and a king. Here is my thought process.

We have 5 slots to fill. Slot 1 must contain only kings and there are 4 of them ($4 \times \_ \times \_ \times\_ \times \_$).

We must remove the 4 kings from the deck so we have 48 cards to choose from. We then choose 1 card from the 48, meaning we have $_{48}C_{1} = 48$ possibilities ($4 \times 48 \times \_ \times\_ \times \_$).

Note that there are 4 such cards and there $_{4}C_{2} = 6$ possible pairs ($4 \times 48 \times 6 \times\_ \times \_$).

We then remove those 4 cards and we are left with 44 and choosing 1 from the remaining cards we get ($4 \times 48 \times 6 \times 44 \times \_$).

After the choice, we have $_{4}C_{2} = 6$ possible pairings ($4 \times 48 \times 6 \times 44 \times 6 = 304128$).

Hence we have 304128 hands.

Answer (score 2):

That is a lot of overcounting. There are only $13$ ranks and one of them is king. Keeping kings aside, as you want two pairs of different ranks, you need to choose $2$ ranks from the $12$ ranks and then $2$ cards each from selected ranks. Also, there are $4$ ways to choose one of the kings.

So the answer should be,

$ \displaystyle 4 \cdot {12 \choose 2} {4 \choose 2} {4 \choose 2} = 9504$

The flaw with your approach -

After taking out $4$ kings, you are picking a card from $48$ cards and now you want a second card of the same rank so ${4 \choose 2}$ is not correct. Even if you choose the second card from the remaining $3$ cards of the same rank, there is overcounting as the order does not matter in the hand. For example, say, you choose $A_S$ (Ace of Spade) as part of $48 \choose 1$  and $A_D$ (Ace of Diamond) from the remaining $3$. But as part of $48 \choose 1$, one of the selections will also be $A_D$ and then you could choose $A_S$ from remaining three. Those are duplicate selections and hence leads to overcounting.